# Let $\overrightarrow{a}=\overrightarrow{b}\times \overrightarrow{c}$

Tags: vectors, cross-product

**I encountered this problem in one of the tests:
Let $\overrightarrow{a}=\overrightarrow{b}\times \overrightarrow{c}$.
If $\overrightarrow{a}=\hat{i}+\hat{j}-\hat{k}$ and $\overrightarrow{c}=\hat{2i}-\hat{3j}+\hat{2k}$.
Then total number of $\overrightarrow{b}$ such that $|\overrightarrow{b}|\epsilon \{1,2....10\}$.**

My approach was to assume the $\overrightarrow{b}=\alpha\hat{i}+\beta\hat{j}+\gamma\hat{j}$, take the cross product with $\overrightarrow{c}$ (using the determinant) and then compare it with $\overrightarrow{a}$, to get the required value. But the value that I am getting, gives the absolute value of $\overrightarrow{b}<1$, so should the answer be $0$, or is there something else that I am missing?

Here is the image of the question for reference.

[image: Image of question for reference]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of possible vectors $\vec{b}$ is zero, since $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{c}$ are not perpendicular. The information about the magnitude $|\vec{b}|$ is irrelevant.

$\vec c \cdot (\vec b \times \vec c)$ is always zero, but $\vec{c} \cdot \vec{a} = +2-3-2=-3$

Comment: Then how come this equation is satisfied if they are not perpendicular. I mean technically $\overrightarrow{a}$ should be perpendicular to both the vectors, isn't it?

Comment: The equation is never satisfied.

Comment: Like if say $x$ belongs to the set of Real number and you have the equation $x^2+1=0$, again here also it would never be satisfied . So is it something like this?

Comment: Well, the three equations $\vec a= \hat\imath + \hat\jmath - \hat k$, $\vec c = 2\hat\imath -3\hat\jmath + 2\hat k$, and $a = \vec b \times \vec c$ can't all be true at once.

Comment: Similar, yes. Or with multiple variables, in the system $x+y+z=1$, $x+2y+3z=2$, $2x+3y+4z=5$, any two of the equations can be true, but not all three. Your determinant method should have given a system of that sort, with no solutions.